# How to put a loop in switch statement? PHP

Tags: php, database, loops, switch-statement

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM table";
$pUN  = $conn->query($stmt)->fetchAll();

$post = empty($_GET['post']) ? '' : $_GET['post'];
$paginas = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];

if ($post != '' || ($post == '' && $paginas != '')) {
switch ($paginas):
    case " ":
        $titulo = " ";
        $shareTitulo = " ";

        $descricao = " ";
        $shareDescricao = " ";

        $shareImg = ' ';
        $keywords = ' ';

        $ogUrl = ' ';
        $urlCanonico = ' ';
        break;

    default:
        $titulo = '';
        $paginas = '';

endswitch;


switch ($post):

    case " ":
        $titulo = " ";
        $shareTitulo = " ";

        $descricao = " ";
        $shareDescricao = " ";

        $shareImg = ' ';
        $keywords = ' ';

        $ogUrl = ' ';
        $urlCanonico = ' ';
        break;

endswitch;

} else {
    $titulo = 'Notícia';
  }
```

I want to put a loop in `switch ($post)` the values of the variables on the `switch ($post)` will be in my database.

How can i put a loop in the `switch ($post)` to get the data from my database? I have a table called "SwitchCase" and i will put the values of the variables in this table.

Edit:

I would have to writte so many switch-case, so instead of this I want to simply writte the values of the variables in the `case` on my table and i want this loop to return the data.

Example:

```
$stmtUN = "SELECT * FROM table";
$pUN    = $conn->query($stmtUN)->fetchAll();

switch ($post):

    foreach ($pUN as $UN): 

        case 'echo $UN["title"]':
            $titulo = 'echo $UN["title"]':
            $shareTitulo = 'echo $UN["title"]':

            $descricao = 'echo $UN["text"]':
            $shareDescricao = 'echo $UN["text"]':

            $shareImg = 'echo $UN["img"]':
            $keywords = 'echo $UN["keywords"]':

            $ogUrl = 'echo $UN["cnc"]':
            $urlCanonico = 'echo $UN["cnc"]':
        break;

    endforeach;

endswitch;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have put the switch block in a wrong place. See the corrected code. Also is there a reason to put the 'echo' string as part of the variable?

```
$stmtUN = "SELECT * FROM table";
$pUN    = $conn->query($stmtUN)->fetchAll();

foreach ($pUN as $UN): 
   echo $UN["title"];

   switch ($post):

      case $UN["title"]:

        $titulo = 'echo $UN["title"]':
        $shareTitulo = 'echo $UN["title"]':

        $descricao = 'echo $UN["title"]':
        $shareDescricao = 'echo $UN["title"]':

        $shareImg = 'echo $UN["title"]':
        $keywords = 'echo $UN["title"]':

        $ogUrl = 'echo $UN["title"]':
        $urlCanonico = 'echo $UN["title"]':
        break;

   endswitch;

endforeach;
```

Comment: @Susi This answer looks correct based on your edit